# How can I only use ng-animate on ng-views, and not ng-repeats?

Tags: angularjs

When using Angular 1.2 with the ngAnimate module, it's working fine on ng-views, but it also is applied to ng-repeats. And when there is a lot, it is quite a performance hit after sorting.

Is there a way to not animate the ng-repeats? I've tried just using the ng-animate with the controller, but it seems that it must be loaded at the app level, and then it is applied to everything.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is use $animate.enabled( false ) just before changing the list in the controller, and re-enabled it shortly after via a $timeout.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-animate` will only animate based on classes, try making unique classes for the animations and only apply them to where you need them in your case.

For example:

```
<div ng-init="items=['a','b','c','d','e','x']">
  <input placeholder="filter" ng-model="f" />
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:f" class="repeat-item">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, when defining the actual CSS animation code for that ngRepeat item, the CSS selector code looks like so:

```
.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
}

.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
.repeat-item.ng-leave,
.repeat-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

(Taken from YearOfMoo excellent write up on new ng-animate:   )

Comment: Thanks, but I did not have any classes for the repeated items, and there was quite a performance hit when the number of items in the list was changed. No problem with sorting, but if there was, say, 100 items which were then filtered to 50 by the user, there was a few seconds delay with ngAnimate included. i.e. that's even with no animation set on the ng-repeat items.